# PowerShell script needed for collecting mailbox properties from each O365 user

Tags: c#, powershell

I need a (single) Powershell script to collect the following attributes from each Office 365 User:

1. DisplayName
2. UserPrincipalName
3. ForwardingAddress
4. ForwardingSmtpAddress
5. DeliverToMailboxAndForward
6. IsMailboxEnabled
7. AutoReplyState
8. InternalMessage
9. ExternalMessage

Numbers 1-6 are obtained from the command `Get-MailBox`. Numbers 7-9 are obtained from the command `Get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration` (for a single user). To get the AutoReplyConfiguration for all users we can pipe the results of `Get-Mailbox` into `Get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration` with the command `Get-MailBox | Get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration`.

Once we have the `Collection<PSObject> results` we can collect the attributes by using code to iterate through the collection like so:

`string displayName = (string) result.Properties["DisplayName"].Value;`

What I would like is a way to collect all 9 of the aforementioned attributes in one script. So far I am only able to first call `Get-MailBox`, collect the results into a dictionary, then use `Get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration`, collect the results, find its user out of the dictionary, and apply the remaining attributes. I need to call the script and collect the results in C#.

The purpose of combining these two actions into one action is to reduce the overall time for the query. If doing so is not actually more efficient let me know and I will continue with my current course of action. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of creating your own objects is to add script methods or simply NoteProperties to existing objects. (Be sure to explicitly select all the properties you need)

```
$MailBoxes = Get-MailBox | Foreach-Object { 
$autoConfig = $_ | Get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration
$_ | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name AutoReplyState -Value $autoConfig.AutoReplyState 
$_ | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name InternalMessage -Value $autoConfig.InternalMessage
$_ | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name ExternalMessage -Value $autoConfig.ExternalMessage
}

$MailBoxes | Select-Object *
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-6